Manim not working on MAC after completing all the steps from the website (doesn’t work on PyCharm, VSCode etc
I went through the manim community forum to download it for a personal project I want to use. Pycharm keeps raising an Import Error: dlopen…: symbol not found in flat namespace ‘_cairo_append_path’
VSCode tells me it cannot find python
Jupyter Lab just gives me a runtime error
Any help is appreciated!
I tried reinstalling things, changing path names, nothing seemed to work. It seemed in my installation of ffmpeg a lot of symlinks were not connected upon installation but I manually linked them. I’m thinking the error is in a path somewhere but I can’t figure out what’s wrong.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
